# How can I avoid repetitive commands, such as cd in a target rule?

Tags: gnu-make

In my makefile I have many `cd $(d)` commands, one for each simple command of a target.
Is there any way to reduce the number of `cd $(d)` commands?

```
all:
    cd $(d); command1
    cd $(d); command2
    cd $(d); command3
    cd $(d); command4
    cd $(d); command5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a shell script that CDs to `$d` first as *make*'s `${SHELL}`.

```
.PHONY: all
all: SHELL := ./cd-to-d
all: .SHELLFLAGS :=
all:
    command1
    command2
    command3
    command4
```

We use target specific variables so as not to disturb other commands in the makefile.

It gets a bit messy if we add the rule to create `cd-to-d` though.

```
cd-to-d: SHELL := ${SHELL}
cd-to-d: .SHELLFLAGS := ${.SHELLFLAGS}
cd-to-d:
    echo '#!/bin/bash' >$@-tmp
    echo 'cd "$d"' >>$@-tmp
    echo 'exec "$$@"' >>$@-tmp
    chmod a+x $@-tmp
    mv $@-tmp $@

.PHONY: all
all: SHELL := ./cd-to-d
all: .SHELLFLAGS :=
all: cd-to-d
all:
    command1
    command2
    command3
    command4
```

Why all the `$@-tmp` noise? If we get an error while creating `cd-to-d`, we don't want to leave an old one lying around. You could use `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` instead (I always do).

Why the `SHELL := ${SHELL}` noise? When *make* builds `cd-to-d` as a dependency of `all`, it will inherit `all`'s target specific defines. We need to cancel those concerned with changing the recipe shell.

Yuk.

Comment: I tried, it work!  **thanks**
<br/>


inline `    tmp $ cat Makefile
    all: SHELL := cd /share/;sh
    all:
        pwd
        ls
</pre>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use line continuation and pass the shell just one line where commands are separated by semicolons:

```
all:
    cd $(d); \
    command1; \
    command2; \
    command3; \
    command4; \
    command5
```

Or even

```
all:
    cd $(d); command1; command2; command3; command4; command5
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive make?

```
.PHONY: all
all: ; ${MAKE} -C $d all-in-d

PHONY: all-in-d
all-in-d:
    command1
    command2
    command3
    command4
```